# Android LiveData Room referenced entities of entity not updated after activity transition

Tags: kotlin, android-room, android-livedata

**Sumary**

In my application I do have a recyclerview displaying objects having items allocated to them within my main activity. With a button people are able to allocate further items which is done in a separate activity (let's call that activity **one**). People are also able to create new objects with another button in, again, another activity (activity **two**). The relationship between the objects and the items is a one-to-many-relationship with objects having multiple items. I use Room and LiveData to display this information.

When users add a new object via activity **two** and the activity is closed then the LiveData on the main screen is updated showing the new object. If they add further items to existing objects with activity **one** then this is not displayed within the main screen. It seems like the LiveData does not recognize changes being done to relationships in activity **one**.

Do you have any idea how I can fix that and update my main screen showing the updated items for the objects?

**Explanation**

The recyclerview contains cardviews displaying the objects and the amount of items allocated to them. When the user clicks on the cardview a detail activity is shown where they are able to add further items to the object. When the user finishes his task and closes the detail activity the main screen is shown again with the data I've told you before. The amount of allocated items, however, does not change.

The main activity contains a bottom navigation, therefore the displayed object views live within a fragment. To observe the livedata I do the following in the **onCreateView** Method:

```kotlin
private fun bindViewModelObservers(){
        // Update the adapter with the result list.
        _viewModel.subscribedProviders.observe(
            viewLifecycleOwner,
            Observer { providers ->
                _providerAdapter.submitList(providers)
            }
        )
    }
```

I use the viewLifecycleOwner as this is best practice concerning fragment destruction, recreation and avoiding memory leaks.
If I replace the **viewLifecycleOwner** with a call to **requireActivity()** then my desired behavior is visible: The user opens the detail activity, adds items to the object, closes the activity and the LiveData of the main screen fragment is updated with the correct amount of allocated items.

I want to refrain from using **requireActivity()** for aforementioned reasons. I appreciate any help, thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds like `subscribedProviders` is not correct?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I don't see a problem with that LiveData object. It does indeed work as it shows the correct amount of allocated items in the first step. It does simply not get the update. I sort of think that this is a problem due to the m-to-n relationship, because I never figured these errors on my other 1-to-n relationships. I did check the developer notes multiple times on this type of relationships but can't find an error in my code at that place either.